# Functional Equation for $f(x-y)+f(y-z)+f(z-x)=2f(x+y+z)$

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

The following functional equation proved quite difficult.

$1.$ $f(x)$ is a polynominal with real coeffecients.

$2.$ $f(1)=2,f(2)=20$.

$3.$ When for real $x,y,z$ satisfies the condition  $xy+yz+zx=0$, $$f(x-y)+f(y-z)+f(z-x)=2f(x+y+z)$$

Find $f(x)$ that satisfies all conditions given above.

While it is easy enough to guess that $f(x)=x^4+x^2$, proving it proved difficult.

First, putting in $(x,0,0)$ gives us that $f(-x)=f(x)$.

Second, putting in $(0,0,0)$ gives us $f(0)=0$

I also substituted $f(x)=g(x^2)$. 
However, I was able to progress no further from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can eliminate $z$ and say that $f(x^2+2xy)+f(y^2+2xy)+f(x^2-y^2)=2f(x^2+xy+y^2)$ for (almost?) all $x,y$.  That is satisfied by both $f(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=x^4$, hence by any linear combination of them.

Comment: The terms of highest degree in my equation come from the highest-degree term in the polynomial $f$.  So if the equation is true for $f$, it is also true for $f's$ leading term alone.  So you only have to solve for $f(x)=x^n$.  Look at the coefficients of a couple of leading terms, say $x^{2n-1}y$ and $x^{2n-2}y^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some comments from Michael, and upon further examination, I was able to formulate a solution.

$f(x-y)+f(y-z)+f(z-x)=2f(x+y+z)$. If $f(x)=g(x^2)$, this gives us that 
$g(x^2-2xy+y^2)+g(y^2-2yz+z^2)+g(z^2-2zx+x^2)=2g(x^2+y^2+z^2)$.

From the fact that $xy+yz+zx=0$. If $x-y=s,y-z=t$, then $x-z=s+t$. This gives us that $xy+yz+zx=(y+s)y+y(y-t)+(y+s)(y-t)=3y^2+2(s-t)y-st=0$. $b^2-4ac=4(s^2+st+t^2)>0$. Thus such a $y$ always exists.

Notice that $s^2+st+t^2=x^2-2xy+y^2+y^2-2yz+z^2-zx-y^2+xy+yz=x^2+y^2+z^2$

Then, $g(s^2)+g(t^2)+g(s^2+2st+t^2)=2g(s^2+st+t^2)$ gives us that $2g(s^2)+g(4s^2)=2g(3s^2)$. If the degree of $g(x)$ is $n$, comparing the coeffecients give us that $2 \times 1 +4^n=2 \times 3^n$. The only solution for this is $n=1,2$. It is easy to proceed from here.

Comment: Is my solution correct? I`m not sure.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari It is not equivalent to $t=0$. It is equivalent to $s=t$.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari What does <br> mean?

Comment: In the case when $s=t$, we will have $x+z=2y$. In that case, $xy+yz+zx=y(z+x)+zx=2y^2+zx=0$ From $zx=-2y^2$ and $x+z=2y$, $x=y+\sqrt {3}y$ and $z=y-\sqrt{3}y$, or the other way around

Answer (score 1):

Here There is no need to assume $f(x)=g(x^2)$, just assume $f(x)$ to be a real polynomial of degree 'n'. Eliminate z by taking $x-y = r,y-z = s$. Then invoke the polynomial equation and apply it to each term in both sides of given equation and by comparing you can arrive that $$f(x) = ax^2 +bx^4$$